# fastJSON ToJSON into dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, json, fastjson

How to use fastJSON (or some other JSON lib, possibly) to dump some data into a dictionary format, e.g. `{"key1": "valstring", "key2": 1234}`?

If I try to dump `Dictionary<string, Object>` I get something like `[{"k":"key1","v":"valstring"},{"k":"key2","v":1234}]` instead.

Comment: Why would you want the contents of the object to be mixed up? It's fine to access them at `json[0]['k']` or `json[1]['k']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) at our office.  We send json objects between python and C#.  We ran into the same problem, though ours was just the differences in how the languages naturally serialized it.

The best part about it, if I'm remember correctly, is that it had this behavior right out of the box.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("key", "val");
dict.Add("key2", "val2");

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Json should equal `{ "key": "val", "key2": "val2" }`

Comment: You mean _"Json should equal `{ "key": "val", "key2": "val2" }`"_?

Answer (score 1):

You just can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to create your solution, it's native for .Net.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("key", "val");
dict.Add("key2", "val2");

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(dict);
```

And you'l get result you are expected: {"key1": "valstring", "key2": 1234}

Answer (score 0):

(fastJSON) You need use some parameters parameters:

```
_jsonParameters = new JSONParameters
        {
            EnableAnonymousTypes = true,
            SerializeToLowerCaseNames = true,
            UseFastGuid = false,
            KVStyleStringDictionary = false <---- THIS
        };
    }

JSON.ToJSON(obj, _jsonParameters)
```